# runing multiple tasks in the one batch not working

Tags: batch-file

I have the following bat file which analyzes the file sizes greater then 10000kb (okay that's not big but its to test things at the moment. then i want it to prompt a message box and open the `P:\bogfiles` directory but my batch doesn't do that, it only wants to complete one task which is moving the files.

How can I get multiple functions running in coneseeion of each other when files greater then X (or 10000kb in our tests example) have been found?

```
pushd c:\Myfolder
md P:\bigfiles2
for %%a in (*.*) do if %%~za gtr 10000 move %%a P:\bigfiles2
```

Comment: Your code doesn't really reflect your question, can you put it in a nutshell what your trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Like Bali C said, your question doesn't reflect your code. You state that your script doesn't want to do any other task other than moving the files. your code doesn't appear to have any other task to complete.

If you're asking how to get it so you can make it do more than one command, there are several ways. You can put them in a block (which is the most common method) or you can abuse the ampersand (&). e.g

```
pushd c:\Myfolder
md P:\bigfiles2
for %%a in (*.*) do if %%~za gtr 10000 (
move %%a P:\bigfiles2
msg * "Is this what you were referring to as a a message box?"
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "P:\bogfiles"
)
```

Or

```
pushd c:\Myfolder
md P:\bigfiles2
for %%a in (*.*) do if %%~za gtr 10000 move %%a P:\bigfiles2 & msg * "This is very messy code." & %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "P:\bogfiles"
```

The bottom example should almost **never** be used as it renders your code unreadable to most other programmers.